# Komodo - "view line numbers" : How to see more than 2 characters

Tags: komodo

I use Komodo Edit and I would like to have more than 2 characters, at least in my Output.

[image: 97 98 99 00 01 02]

Of course, I Googled this question, but I can't see any answer.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: I think it's something silly like closing and reopening the file or restarting Komodo that fixes this.  It sounds really familiar but i can't find anything about it.  What colour scheme are you using?

Comment: Thanks, but I tried and it's still the same thing. I use 'Classic'...